# How to get the IntelXDK Facebook Key Hash

Tags: html, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

can anyone tell me how I can get my hands on the Facebook Keyhash, am using the included facebook plugin in IntelXDK:

com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect

But for the life of me can't figure out how to get the KeyHASH. Any help really appreciated, as I've been on the intelXDK forum too and couldn't find a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel's support team got back to me and showed me a relatively new article on how to get the hash. I thought I'd share it, in case anyone else was having trouble:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/facebook-android-keyhash